# Trying to map a variable to another in parent class using Jackson

Tags: json, jackson

```
class Parent{

 private String relevance;

}

class Child extends Parent{

private String score;

}
```

in my response sometimes i get score and sometime relevance. I want to map score to relevance anytime i get that as the response.

Is there any way to do it using Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could do it in next way:

```
class Parent{

  private String relevance;
  @JsonProperty("relevance")
  public void setRelevance(String relevance) {
    this.relevance = relevance;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent{

  @JsonProperty("score")
  public void setScore(String score) {
     this.relevance = score;
  }
}
```

So either you will get `score` or `relevance` in response you will map it to `relevance` field.